# NoClassDefFoundError in Flutter app which has kotlin library dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

in my flutter app , i have a kotlin library dependency.in the main activity on android folder, i am calling one of library`s functions, which it has a lambda in it.

for example : a.b.c.Util.someFunction$1

i am calling "someFunction" from MainActivity and it crashes because it says that it cant find  "$1" class.i am aware that kotlin creates a class for each lambda and names it as such(with $ sign).

fun fact is , the app runs in my android 7 device , but it crashes on android 4 and 5 device.

my best guess was that i am using source compatibility of version 8 for kotlin compiler and it generates java 8 compatible bytecode so lower devices dont support it, but even downgrading it to version 6 didnt solve the problem

i have added multidex support to build.gradle and have extended FlutterApplication and have called Multidex.install(this) at my Application class and have replaced my Application class in manifest

Answer (score 0):

i found the root of problem.i am using some of the jdk8 functions in kotlin code and it is not supported on older devices because they are jvm 6 or 7.

for example Collection.removeIf or Map.forEach function  is defined in jdk8

i managed to solve this issue by finding and replacing all jdk8 function calls by lowering language level of intellij idea to 6.but it only forces you to use only language features under 6 and not functions.i think now i have to find all jdk8 function in the heystack!